# Exercise on Borel Cantelli Lemma ($\limsup X_n/ \ln(n) =1$ a.s.) help required to rigorously write the statement

Tags: probability, self-study

I hope this question is within the scope of this site. Please note that I have *solved* this Exercise, I do have doubts about my presentation though and about how to rigorously empathize on the arguments.

> **Problem:** Let $(X_n)_{n \geq 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d. RV with exponential distribution (standard, parameter 1). Show that $$\limsup \frac{X_n}{\ln(n)} =1  \text{ a.s.} $$

**"Proof"**: As before mentioned I do understand the idea behind this proof, my problem lies in the presentation. I will highlight the important steps that I do not understand.

Certainly since $X_n \sim X \sim {}$Exponential(1) we have for all $t>0$ that  $$P(X_n \geq t) = \int_t^\infty e^{-x}dx = e^{-t} $$

Now let $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ be fixed but arbitrary, we then get $$P(X_n/\ln(n) \geq 1- \epsilon ) =\frac{1}{n^{1-\epsilon}} \implies \sum P(X_n/\ln(n) \geq 1- \epsilon) = \infty  $$
Since our sequence of RV is i.i.d. we can use Borel Cantelli 2 to conclude that  $$P( \limsup \lbrace X_n/ \ln(n) \geq 1-\epsilon \rbrace ) = 1  $$ 
Please note the braces $\lbrace \cdot \rbrace$ here, they will later on contribute to my confusion. Since the above statement is true for all $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ I can let $\epsilon =  \frac{1}{k}$ for $k > 1$ and then define $$A_k:= \lbrace \limsup X_n/\ln(n) \geq 1 - 1/k \rbrace $$

> **Question 1:** I have seen the above being done before. Namely the $\limsup$ which was 'outside' of the event (namely outside the brackets) is now inside the event. Is this step okay? How can I be certain that pulling the $\limsup$ inside the event will still give me an event that has probability $1$?

Now I know that $P(A_k)=1$ for all $k>1$, therefore $P(\bigcap A_k$)=1 and therefore I have
 $$\omega \in \bigcap A_k  \iff \limsup (X_n(\omega) /  \ln(n)) \geq 1 - 1/k \ , \forall k >1  \\ \implies \limsup  X_n/\ln(n) \geq 1 \ \text{ almost surely}$$

---

Now for other direction I want to go a similar route. Here I run into trouble though. Obviously for $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ I have  $$ P ( X_n/\ln (n) \geq 1+\epsilon)= \frac{1}{n^{\epsilon +1}} $$
Similar as in the above steps I will this time end up with a finite sum, hence by Borel Cantelli 1st. Version I obtain that  $$P (\limsup \lbrace X_n/ \ln(n) \geq 1+\epsilon \rbrace) = 0  $$
Here my problem is that I obviously want to consider the complementary event, but that will give me the statement that $$P ( \liminf \lbrace X_n/\ln(n) \leq 1+ \epsilon \rbrace ) =1 $$
Ultimately, following the same procedure as above, I would also show that $$ \liminf X_n/ \ln(n) \leq 1 \text{ almost surely} $$
But I have doubts about this being true. This would give me statement that $$ \lim X_n/ \ln(n) =1 \text{ almost surely} $$ of course I could also then say that $\lim, \limsup, \liminf$ are all equal in this case, but I don't think that's what I am supposed to show.

> **Question 2:** What am I supposed to do in order to show that $\limsup X_n/ \ln(n) \leq 1$ ? (Partially answered by myself, see update)

**Update:** Given that $$ P(\limsup \lbrace X_n/\ln(n) > 1+ \epsilon  \rbrace )=0, \ \forall \epsilon \in (0,1) $$
We can set that $$A_k= \limsup \lbrace  X_n/ \ln(n) > 1+ 1/k \rbrace  $$
Which is a nullset. Then we get by the subaddivitiy of $P$ that $$P(\cup A_k) \leq \sum P(A_k)=0  \implies \cup A_k = \limsup \lbrace X_n/\ln(n) > 1 \rbrace  \text{ is nullset} $$

So I believe what is left for me to understand to complete and fully grasp this exercise is:

> **Question 3:** Why do we have $$ \lbrace \limsup X_n/ \ln (n) >1 \rbrace \subset \bigcup_k \limsup \lbrace X_n/ \ln(n) > 1 + 1/k \rbrace  \\ \bigcap_k \ \limsup \lbrace X_n/\ln(n) \geq 1 - 1/k \rbrace  \subset \lbrace \limsup X_n/ \ln(n) \geq 1 \rbrace $$

Question 3 is more general than 1 and 2 and would also answer them. I think this statement might be general. So  if I am lucky I might find it in a measure theory/probability theory book.

Comment: You haven't quite understood Borel-Cantelli, and the difference helps with your question 1.   The $\lim \sup$ is as $n \to \infty$, so you don't need to define $A_k$ at all; it's already part of your previous equation.  "Almost surely" is the same as "with probability 1", so you're done at the $P(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \dots)$ line.  This might help you with part 2 as well.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @jbowman. I do know that by definition $$P ( \lbrace \omega \in \Omega: : \lim X_n(\omega) = X(\omega)\rbrace ) = 1 \iff X_n \to X \text{ almost surely} $$ 
However I just have shown that $$ P( \limsup \lbrace  X_n/\ln(n)-1 \geq -\epsilon \rbrace ) = 1  $$ I think some extra steps are required (for a beginner like me) to go from the above to $$ \limsup X_n/\ln(n) = 1 \text{ almost surely}$$ or do I understand you wrong? Also what "difference" do you mean?

Comment: +1 for showing admirable effort! However, this is a very, very, long question. Would you be able to break it up into several questions? Each one would possibly require decent post.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Bey, I do absolutely agree with you! I got lost in equations and during the process my post became way too lengthy. I will break this question apart and most likely split it into two separate questions.